# Getting the following error no single-String constructor/factory method

Tags: java, json, jackson

Below is the json string that i am parsing using jackson in java

```
String rspString = "{\"currency\": [{\"USD\": [\"U.S.Dollar\",\"$\"]},\"USD\"]}";

JsonUtil jsonUtil = new JsonUtil();
        API1Response configAPI1Rsp = new API1Response();
        API1Rsp = (API1Response) jsonUtil.Json2Object(rspString, configAPI1Rsp);

public class API1Response 
{
   @JsonProperty("Currency")
   public List<Currency> currency;
   //getters and setters
}

public class Currency()
{
   @JsonProperty("USD")
   public List<USD> USD

  //getters and Setters
}
```

when i run the above code i am getting the below error:

> Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.sample.test.Currency] from String value ('USD'); no single-String constructor/factory method

in the above response string how to treat USD ( last one in the object) how to define in java for that object.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the code posted above correct? does it compile? `public class Currency()` I think it should not have parenthesis () Please post exact working code

Comment: Also add the constructors of the Currency class. I think there might not be one that takes a single string or no arguments also you probably don't have a factory method.

Comment: sorry for that typo, their is no "()" for the class currency . can u please give an example so that it will guide me in right path

Answer (score 0):

Your currency key in Json is array of Object and a String whilst you are converting array of Objects to Java object. So you need to modify the json string such that it only contains the objects. I.e. second element "USD" is not the object hence you are getting the error "no single-String constructor/factory method".

Comment: the json string is developed in that way cannot remove that element USD as it is a requirement. please help me how to get the values from json .

Comment: can you share your USD class

Comment: USD is an array having values i have declared as empltypublic class USD
{
   
}

Answer (score 0):

@JsonProperty("Currency") - Make sure "Currency" should be in lower case as it is in json string.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
public class wallet {
    List<Currency> currency;
}
```

and

```
"{\"currency\": [{\"USD\": [\"U.S.Dollar\",\"$\"]},]}"; or
"{\"currency\": [{\"USD\": [\"U.S.Dollar\",\"$\"]},\"USD\":[]]}";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.